# How to programmatically use Prism's NavigationService?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, prism, navigationservice

I implemented and it works navigation with NavigationService by Prism:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("FirstPage?title=FirstPage");
}

protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>("MainPage");
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstPage>("FirstPage");
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstPage>("SecondPage");
}
```

In command of particular button I implement for example:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("FirstPage");
```

very easy, BUT. What If I want to:

Go to the first page, check something and if it's true immediately go to the "Second Page"? It doesn't work! The button must be clicked otherwise navigation doesn't work

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. On your FirstPage or FirstPageViewModel you must implement **INavigatedAware** interface.
2. On **NavigatedTo**(this will get called once you navigate to FirstPage) you should check the condition and Navigate to  SecondPage if true

Example of doing it on your FirstPage class:

```
public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage, INavigatedAware
{
    INavigationService _navigationService;
    bool myCondition = true;

    public FirstPage(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if(myCondition == true)
        {
           _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage");
        }
    }
 }
```